# How to make a mapped key revert back to default behavior

Tags: vim

I've started to use vim in college on my schools afs server running SunOS
One of the problems I'm occurring is a default Ctrl W key mapping which prints out a bunch of text
I checked the mappings and found this:

`<C-W>         :w<CR>Go<Esc>:$r!spell %<CR>`

Can someone assist me on how to restore it to the normal split screen navigation controls?

Answer (score 22):

Put this in your .vimrc: `:unmap <C-W>`